# 16ms delay in call to BitBl()

Tags: windows, sdl, direct3d11

I am using SDL 2.0.13 on Windows 10 and I've been timing the calls to `SDL_RenderPresent`. After a long test, I see that *exactly* 1 in 62 frames takes 16ms instead of the expected 1..2ms. Filing the SDL lib with debug I traced this to the call to `BitBlt()`, so it's a Windows/OS/Driver/... issue not SDL. Clearly there must be something going on here tied to vsync. The problem can be seen using Direct3D 11 or software renderers. And does not seem affected by `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC`.

Originally asked here https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl-renderpresent-bitblt-16ms-pause/28070 but as this is not an SDL issue I was posting the question wider.

What is going on? Can I stop it or avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't affected by vsync - shouldn't you have (ideally) every frame at 16.6ms with vsync on (on 60Hz monitor)? Have you tried different workload (i.e. separately testing with single clear&present, with few draws&present, and with a lot of draws&present) - do you still have the same result? What's your GPU and driver?

Comment: Hi,There is an SDL option SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC which is meant to control vsync'ing, but setting it (or not) makes no difference to my stats. The main app does lots of updates to the bitmap, but the actual renderpresent is just the single final rectangle to the [desktop] window. 98.4% of the time the BitBlt takes 1..2ms, and 1.6% of the time it takes 16ms. Never any values in between

Comment: Could it be that your graphics driver's settings override vsync? This is all implementation-specific, but I could easily imagine situation when driver sometimes locks until next vsync even if vsync is generally disabled. Unless your requirements are very specific - I'd say generally best solution is to actually enable vsync, so every frame'd be 16.6ms.

Comment: The effect seems independent of GPU -- seen on NVidia [Quadro] and integrated Intel HD. I can see that a driver may lock until vsync, what doesn't make sense is the delay is EITHER "0ms" or "16ms" - never any intermediate values. Ideally I want no delay in my main app as there's other processing to be done. I just want to hand off the present/blt to happen 'as soon as...'

Comment: I think there’s a bug deep inside SDL. Under the hood, monitor refresh rates aren’t integers, they’re rational numbers. The 60Hz of the monitor I’m looking at right now delivers 59997/1000 = 59.997Hz. When using sufficiently low-level APIs like DXGI (Windows) or DRM/KMS (Linux), you can obtain the precise rational value. Pretty sure somewhere deep inside SDL they are rounding these rational numbers to integers.

Comment: Hi, my timings are directly around the call to BitBlt within the render code